# C# Get distinct sub-list of ints using Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of a list of ints: `List<List<int>>` that for simplicity's sake has the value `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. How can I use Linq to get all the distinct sublists? Which in this case would be just `[1, 2, 3]`.

I tried `.Distinct()` as well as `.GroupBy(x => x)` paired with `.Select(x => x.First())`, but with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a home task or you are solving a real-world problem? If the later one, the approach you are trying to take is doubtful.

Comment: Use JetBrains' DotPeek to look at the code for the `Distinct` extension method. It probably uses some method for comparing equality between items. See if there's some way to inject a hand-written `IEqualityComparer` implementation into the process. Looking at the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-distinct-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0))) ), it looks like you can. All you need to do is roll your own comparer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should define when `List<int>` are equal and implement corresponding comparer. For instance, if we assume that

> List `a` equals to list `b` if and only if they contain equal items order and quantity matters:
> `{1, 2, 3} == {1, 2, 3} != {2, 1, 3} != {1, 1, 2, 3}`

we can come up with

```
private sealed class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
  public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T>? x, IEnumerable<T>? y) =>
     (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) ? true
    : x is null || y is null ? false
    : x.SequenceEqual(y);

  public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) => obj is null ? -1 : obj.Count();
}
```

Then you are ready for `Distinct`:

```
List<List<int>> list = ...

var result = list
  .Distinct(new MyComparer<int>())
  .ToList();
```